# How to see bucket structure that gets stored for the timeseries data in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, time-series, nosql, mongo-shell

I have created a timeseries collection for weather data.

```js
db.createCollection(
    "weather",
    {
       timeseries: {
          timeField: "timestamp",
          metaField: "metadata",
          granularity: "hours"
       }
    }
)
```

When I retrieve the data I get the data as I stored it, but mongoDB stores these data in different way. It creates buckets based on `metaField` and `granularity`.

How to see those original buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB treats time series collections as writable non-materialized views backed by an internal collection.

MongoDB stores system information in collections that use the `<database>.system.*` namespace, which MongoDB reserves for internal use.
`system.buckets` stores the underlying data associated to a time series collection in an optimized format and schema for an efficient representation of the persisted time series data.

In your case, it will be `system.buckets.weather` collection.